# Edge loop reduction at the wrist

Tags: edges, topology, loop

Is this a good idea? Is this going to cause trouble when animating the hand bending and twisting?
If it's incorrect, please could you help and advise where would be the best place to reduce edge loops from arm to hand?

[image: Reduction of high loop count of forearm to low loop count of the hand, at the wrist]

Comment: maybe results in tiny weird deforms when bending because the vertices are not aligned with others making it look like a triangulated faces

Comment: I guess that's a way to do it, but do you need so many vertices for the arm?

Comment: I actually don't think I need that many vertices for the arm now that I am learning how to reduce loops for different parts of the model. I created the model base by sculpting and thus needed it dense. For now I just want to speed up to start learning how to rig and animate the hand.